# Rotate one 3D vector into another 3D vector along a specified direction

Tags: vectors, rotations

I'm trying to figure out what the angle of rotation (sign included) is when you take one 3D vector and rotate it into another 3D vector **specifically when the axis of rotation is specified**.

The image below shows what I'm trying to do (sorry for my rudimentary hand drawing). The angle `theta` is what I'd like to calculate.

Say there's a 3D vector `v` that defines the axis of rotation. Imagine a plane that includes both vector `v` and point `p1`, then we rotate this plane about the axis `v` until it hits point `p2`. The rotation of this plane forms the angle `theta` which is what I'm trying to compute. Note that vector `v` is not necessarily parallel to the cross product of `p1` and `p2`. The origin `o` in my case is just `(0,0,0)`

[image: example rotation]

Comment: So you just want P1 to be moved in the plane of v and OP2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the solution myself, so wanted to post what I came up with. Turned out to be a little more simple than I realized.

First compute a normal vector to the plane formed by `v and p1` and also the plane formed by `v and p2`

```
n1 = ||v X p1||
n2 = ||v X p2||
```

Then I can take these two vectors and compute the angle between them by doing

```
abs_theta = arccos(n1 * n2)
```

This gives me the absolute value of the angle I'm searching for

To get the sign of the rotation I need to compute the cross product of `n1 with n2`

```
v1 = ||n1 X n2||
```

and `dot` it with `v`

```
sign = ((v * v1) > 0) * 2 - 1
```

`sign = 1` if positive rotation and `sign = -1` for negative rotation

Note: Some final logic is needed to take care in the special situation's of `theta = 0 or 180`

Here's a simple Matlab script that does the math. Messing around with the `z` value of `p2` doesn't change the computed angle, which is what I was looking for.

[image: single code example]

Comment: Technically it is similar to my approach as vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ lie in the plane perpendicular  to $v$,  similarly    $v_1$ and $v_2$.  You are right that additional analysis is needed for the sigh of $\theta$. Case $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ is easy to detect.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want find the angle needed to rotate the plane containing both $v$ and $p_1$ until that plane contains $p_2$.

If $p_1\times p_2 = \lambda v$, the angle is simply $\theta(p_1,p_2) = \dfrac{p_1\cdot p_2}{|p_1||p_2|}$.

To make this work for the case where $p_1\times p_2 \neq \lambda v$, we can instead use $\theta(p_1,\hat p_2)$, where $\hat p_2$ is the projection of $p_2$ into the plane containing $p_1$ with normal $v$. Doing this gives us

$$\hat p_2 = p_2 - (v\cdot(p_2-p_1))v$$

[(See this question if you're confused about this step)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605556/2450542)

Note that the rotated point $p_1'$ is a scaled $\hat p_2$, in particular

$$ p_1' = \frac{|p_1|}{|\hat p_2|}\hat p_2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be the vector to be rotated, $\mathbf{x}'$ the rotated vector, $\mathbf{n}$ the unit axis vector ($||\mathbf{n}||=1$) and $\theta$ the rotation angle. The rotated vector then equals to $\mathbf{x}'=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}$, where
\begin{align} \mathbf{R}=\mathbf{I}+\sin\theta\mathbf{N}+2\sin^2(\theta/2)\mathbf{N}^2,~\mathbf{N}=\textbf{Spin}(\mathbf{n})=\left[
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  0         & -n_3 & n_2\\
  n_3  & 0         &-n_1 \\
  -n_2 & n_1  & 0 \\
 \end{array}
 \right] 
\end{align}
Example:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{n}&=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 0\\
 1\\
\end{array}
\right],~\mathbf{x}=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1\\
 0\\
 0\\
\end{array}
\right],~\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\\&\implies\mathbf{N}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -1 & 0\\
 1 & 0 &0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right],~\mathbf{N}^2=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & -1 &0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right],~\mathbf{x}'=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Just a variation of the above answer.
Project both vectors $p_1$ and $p_2$ onto the plane perpendicular to vector $v$.
It is the plane where rotation acts.

Asumming $v$ is unit vector we have

$v_1= (I-vv^T)p_1$
$v_2= (I-vv^T)p_2$

Now just calculate the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$ using scalar product.
$v_1^Tv_2=\Vert v_1 \Vert \Vert v_2 \Vert \cos \theta $.